# XmlDataProvider Refresh source WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xmldataprovider

I have a WPF Grid

```
<Window x:Class="LabsRSS.Window1"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Title="Poperecinii Timur Lab" Height="404" Width="588">
<Grid x:Name="blah">
    <Grid.Resources>
        <XmlDataProvider x:Key="flickrdata" Source="http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?tags=dog&amp;lang=en-us&amp;format=rss_200">
            <XmlDataProvider.XmlNamespaceManager>
                <XmlNamespaceMappingCollection>
                    <XmlNamespaceMapping Prefix="media" Uri="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/"/>
                </XmlNamespaceMappingCollection>
            </XmlDataProvider.XmlNamespaceManager>
        </XmlDataProvider>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="itemTemplate">
            <Image Width="75" Height="75" Source="{Binding Mode=OneWay, XPath=media:thumbnail/@url}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="controlTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type ItemsControl}">
            <WrapPanel IsItemsHost="True" Orientation="Horizontal"/>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <ItemsControl
   Width="375"
   ItemsSource="{Binding Mode=Default, Source={StaticResource flickrdata}, XPath=/rss/channel/item}"
   ItemTemplate="{StaticResource itemTemplate}"
   Template="{StaticResource controlTemplate}">
    </ItemsControl>
    <TextBox Height="23" Margin="193,0,213,24" Name="textBox1" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" TextChanged="textBox1_TextChanged" />
</Grid>
```

What I try to do is to replace the tag with my own input from TextBox.

```
 private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        XmlDataProvider dataProvider = (XmlDataProvider)this.blah.FindResource("flickrdata");
        XmlNamespaceManager xnManager = dataProvider.XmlNamespaceManager;
        string newSource = "http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?tags=flower&amp;lang=en-us&amp;format=rss_200";
        newSource = Regex.Replace(newSource, "(^.*tags=)(.+?)(&amp;.*$)", String.Format("{0}{1}{2}", "$1", textBox1.Text, "$3"));
        dataProvider.Source = new Uri(newSource);
        dataProvider.XmlNamespaceManager = xnManager;
        dataProvider.Refresh();

    }
```

Now the uri seems to be set good but the dataProvider is not refreshing the content, how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

I actually don't think you want to call Refresh... or *re*-set the XmlNamespaceManger for that matter. I think the call to Refresh is actually telling the XmlDataProvider to reload the same source it already had.

When you change the Source that should be all that's necessary to trigger the loading logic. If you did want to re-set the XmlNamespaceManager you should call DeferRefresh because otherwise the provider will reload on every property change.

Comment: "When you change the Source that should be all that's necessary to trigger the loading logic..."

But it doesn't :(